# Why onBackPressed call my onActivityResult?

Tags: android

I have the following situation, from the main activity I go to the second activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddTaskActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_TASK_REQUEST_CODE);
```

In the second activity, when I try to save data, I call:

```
private void saveTask() {

    String text = editTextTask.getText().toString();
    String date = editTextDate.getText().toString();
    String category = textViewSelectCategory.getText().toString();

    if(!text.trim().isEmpty() && (!date.trim().isEmpty())) {

        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra(TEXT_KEY, text);
        data.putExtra(DATE_KEY, date);
        data.putExtra(CATEGORY_KEY, category);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);

    } else {

        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    }

    finish();
}
```

However, in the main activity I receive data or display AlertDialog:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == ADD_TASK_REQUEST_CODE) {

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            String text = data.getStringExtra(TEXT_KEY);
            String date = data.getStringExtra(DATE_KEY);
            String category = data.getStringExtra(CATEGORY_KEY);

            Task task = new Task(text, category, date);
            viewModelMainActivity.insert(task);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Task saved in " + category + " list!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            buildAlertDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

And here the problem arises, namely why when in the second activity I press the "Back" button and call the onBackPressed method, the buildAlertDialog method from onActivityResult is called?

```
private void back() {

    String text = editTextTask.getText().toString();
    String date = editTextDate.getText().toString();

    if (text.trim().isEmpty() && (date.trim().isEmpty())) {

        onBackPressed();

    } else {

        buildAlertDialog();
    }
}
```

I noticed that if I use startActivity () instead of onBackPressed then everything is fine. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because in the second activity you call `setResult()` method which delivers the result in the first activity only when `onBackPressed ()` or `finish()` is called, this approach it's like a method in some class that returns the result when it's work is done, but in your case the role of method plays an activity

Comment: How could I prevent this? To not call this method in onActivityResult in this case?

Comment: If you remove all the setResult() calls in the second activity then onActivityResult() won't be called when you close the activity, or you can pass different result codes to setResult () method that correspond the event was you activity closed or not. But i'm afraid of that there is no more way to call onActivityResultMethod()